# Absolute numbers question

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

Here’s a question that took a run for my money.

Solve for $x$ for the following

$|x+3|+ |x - 4|\lt 0$

Comment: Well, yeah. That’s why I’m here

Comment: Alrighty then. What do you think i should do? I get an answer that once i place back to the original question, It’s not valid.

Comment: Any thoughts at all ? ... did you notice that the absolute value will always be positive (or zero) and we require a negative result.

Comment: When i say the question, i knew there wasnt any real number that would make it work. It reached a point i started questioning myself, “Am i missing something? Complex number perhaps.”

Comment: Complex numbers won't help.  Absolute values are always 0 or positive.  This is never possible.

Comment: Yes, but the problems comes at representing it. Do you simply type in, “Never possible”, or do I do it like @ArsenBerk.... stating that the solution set is $\varnothing$

Comment: @PyrJames both of these things are equivalent, they just mean that there are no solutions. It doesn't matter how you write it.

Comment: Alright, Thank you Donald, John Doe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three cases to consider:

- **CASE 1 ($x < -3$):** We have $-x-3+4-x<0 \implies x > \frac{1}{2}$ but this is contradicting our first assumption $x < -3$ so there is no solution here.
- **CASE 2 ($4>x>-3$):** We have $x+3+4-x < 0 \implies 7 < 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, there is no solution here.
- **CASE 3 ($x > 4$):** We have $x+3+x-4 < 0 \implies x < \frac{1}{2}$, which is again contradicting our first assumption $x > 4$. So there is no solution here.

Therefore the solution set is $\emptyset$.

Alternatively, we have
$$|x+3| < -|x-4|$$
which is always false since $|x-4| \ge 0$ for all $x$. So the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, didn’t think about it this way. I ended writing an essay on how it’s not possible

Comment: But wait,... what about the alternative part tho...

Comment: Im sorry, nevermind... thank you

Comment: We know that $|x-4| \ge 0$ for all $x$. Since there is a minus sign before it, RHS of the inequality is either $0$ (for $x = 4$) or negative. But LHS cannot be less than $0$ or cannot be less than a negative number so the result follows.

Comment:  Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Actually there is only one case to consider. Splitting things as you suggest is only diverting the OP from the heart of the matter. And they would be at pain to solve for $x$ the inequality $$|x+e^{x}-5\cos x|+|x^7+4x^3+2|<0$$ although its solution is trivial.

Comment: In my alternative solution, I also gave a different approach, which doesn't require splitting the cases. For this question, you might be right but there are some questions which needs to be splitted into cases.

Answer (score 1):

$|x+3| + |x -4| < 0\implies$

$|x+3| < -|x-4|$.

But absolute values are always non-negative so this is impossible.  No solutions.

$|a| + |b| < 0$ is never possible.